# How would I go about getting a value from a Headless-UI component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-state, headless-ui

I'm using a [Headless-UI Listbox component.](https://headlessui.com/react/listbox)

I put this listbox as it's own React component, and I import that component in a settings form. How would I go about grabbing the value from the component and storing it in the state for the settings form(The listbox component already uses onChange)

```js
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import { Listbox, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { CheckIcon, SelectorIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

const people = [
  { name: 'Wade Cooper' },
  { name: 'Arlene Mccoy' },
  { name: 'Devon Webb' },
  { name: 'Tom Cook' },
  { name: 'Tanya Fox' },
  { name: 'Hellen Schmidt' },
]

export default function Example() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(people[0])

  return (
    <div className="fixed top-16 w-72">
      <Listbox value={selected} onChange={setSelected}>
        <div className="relative mt-1">
          <Listbox.Button className="relative w-full cursor-default rounded-lg bg-white py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left shadow-md focus:outline-none focus-visible:border-indigo-500 focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:ring-offset-orange-300 sm:text-sm">
            <span className="block truncate">{selected.name}</span>
            <span className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2">
              <SelectorIcon
                className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
            </span>
          </Listbox.Button>
          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <Listbox.Options className="absolute mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
              {people.map((person, personIdx) => (
                <Listbox.Option
                  key={personIdx}
                  className={({ active }) =>
                    `relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-10 pr-4 ${
                      active ? 'bg-amber-100 text-amber-900' : 'text-gray-900'
                    }`
                  }
                  value={person}
                >
                  {({ selected }) => (
                    <>
                      <span
                        className={`block truncate ${
                          selected ? 'font-medium' : 'font-normal'
                        }`}
                      >
                        {person.name}
                      </span>
                      {selected ? (
                        <span className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 text-amber-600">
                          <CheckIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </span>
                      ) : null}
                    </>
                  )}
                </Listbox.Option>
              ))}
            </Listbox.Options>
          </Transition>
        </div>
      </Listbox>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here's an example of what the Listbox component looks like

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want.

```
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Listbox, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { CheckIcon, SelectorIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

export default function Example({ 
  people, 
  selected, 
  setSelected 
}) {
  return (
    <div className="fixed top-16 w-72">
      <Listbox value={selected} onChange={setSelected}>
        <div className="relative mt-1">
          <Listbox.Button className="relative w-full cursor-default rounded-lg bg-white py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left shadow-md focus:outline-none focus-visible:border-indigo-500 focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:ring-offset-orange-300 sm:text-sm">
            <span className="block truncate">{selected.name}</span>
            <span className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2">
              <SelectorIcon
                className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
            </span>
          </Listbox.Button>
          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <Listbox.Options className="absolute mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
              {people.map((person, personIdx) => (
                <Listbox.Option
                  key={personIdx}
                  className={({ active }) =>
                    `relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-10 pr-4 ${
                      active ? 'bg-amber-100 text-amber-900' : 'text-gray-900'
                    }`
                  }
                  value={person}
                >
                  {({ selected }) => (
                    <>
                      <span
                        className={`block truncate ${
                          selected ? 'font-medium' : 'font-normal'
                        }`}
                      >
                        {person.name}
                      </span>
                      {selected ? (
                        <span className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 text-amber-600">
                          <CheckIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </span>
                      ) : null}
                    </>
                  )}
                </Listbox.Option>
              ))}
            </Listbox.Options>
          </Transition>
        </div>
      </Listbox>
    </div>
  )
}
```

then

```
import { useState } from "react"

export default App() {
  const people = [
    { name: 'Wade Cooper' },
    { name: 'Arlene Mccoy' },
    { name: 'Devon Webb' },
    { name: 'Tom Cook' },
    { name: 'Tanya Fox' },
    { name: 'Hellen Schmidt' },
  ]
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(people[0])

  return (
    <>
      <Example people={people} selected={info} setSelected={setInfo}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```js
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import { Listbox, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { CheckIcon, SelectorIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const people = [
  { name: 'Wade Cooper' },
  { name: 'Arlene Mccoy' },
  { name: 'Devon Webb' },
  { name: 'Tom Cook' },
  { name: 'Tanya Fox' },
  { name: 'Hellen Schmidt' },
]

export default function Example() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(people[0])
  const [valueListBox, setValueListBox] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setValueListBox(selected)
  }, [selected])

  return (
    <div className="fixed top-16 w-72">
      <Listbox value={selected} onChange={setSelected}>
        <div className="relative mt-1">
          <Listbox.Button className="relative w-full cursor-default rounded-lg bg-white py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left shadow-md focus:outline-none focus-visible:border-indigo-500 focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:ring-offset-orange-300 sm:text-sm">
            <span className="block truncate">{selected.name}</span>
            <span className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2">
              <SelectorIcon
                className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
            </span>
          </Listbox.Button>
          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <Listbox.Options className="absolute mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
              {people.map((person, personIdx) => (
                <Listbox.Option
                  key={personIdx}
                  className={({ active }) =>
                    `relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-10 pr-4 ${
                      active ? 'bg-amber-100 text-amber-900' : 'text-gray-900'
                    }`
                  }
                  value={person}
                >
                  {({ selected }) => (
                    <>
                      <span
                        className={`block truncate ${
                          selected ? 'font-medium' : 'font-normal'
                        }`}
                      >
                        {person.name}
                      </span>
                      {selected ? (
                        <span className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 text-amber-600">
                          <CheckIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </span>
                      ) : null}
                    </>
                  )}
                </Listbox.Option>
              ))}
            </Listbox.Options>
          </Transition>
        </div>
      </Listbox>
    </div>
  )
}
```